# How to put a SELECT from Oracle into a bash variable?

Tags: oracle, bash, variables

I try to save the output of an Oracle SELECT command into a bash variable.
I tried the following lines but it didn't work really well...

```
ACCESS_SQL=`{
    sqlplus << EOF
    ${USER}/${PASSWORD}@DB
    set head off;
    set feedback off;
    set pagesize 5000;
    set linesize 30000;
    set serveroutput on;
    DECLARE
    data varchar(5000);
    BEGIN
    select ACCESS_ID, PROFILE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PLATFORM, ACCESS_TYPE, PERM_FLAG, ACTIVE_FLAG into data from uam.access_list where USER_ID='${USER_ID}';
    dbms_output.put_line(data);
    END;
    /
    exit;
EOF
    }`
```

The error statement I get is :

```
SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7      select ACCESS_ID, PROFILE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PLATFORM, ACCESS_TYPE, PERM_FLAG, ACTIVE_FLAG into data from uam.access_list where USER_ID='PZ230';
                                                                                                                *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 110:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 4, column 2:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I was wondering if using a varchar is the right thing to do...

Comment: Does `ORA-00947: not enough values` give you a hint?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `select into` a variable and then use `dbms_output.put_line` to print it out. (Your `select into` statement won't work anyway, because you can't select multiple columns into a single data variable.)

Instead, do it like this:

```
data=$(sqlplus -S ${USER}/${PASSWORD} << EOF
  set head off
  set feedback off
  set pagesize 5000
  set linesize 30000
  select ACCESS_ID, PROFILE_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PLATFORM, ACCESS_TYPE, PERM_FLAG, ACTIVE_FLAG from uam.access_list where USER_ID='${USER_ID}';
  exit
EOF)

echo "$data"
```

Comment: Parenthesis for here-doc must go on the next line, otherwise, you might get an error  like warning: here-document at line nnn delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')